# Need to make a function that deletes info about last student in the list

Tags: c, list, structure

I need to make a function that will delete the info about the last student, and it returns 1 if it is successful or 0 if not.

I'm stuck here, should I use pointers or something, I'm really lost here.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>



/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */




typedef struct _students
{
    int index;
    char name[20];


} students;

int main() {

    int n;

    printf("How much students you want: ");
    scanf("%d" ,&n);

    int i=0;

    struct _students list[n];

    for(i;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Type info about student nbr. %d \n" ,i+1);
        printf("\n");

        printf("index: ");
        scanf("%d", &list[i].index);

        printf("name: ");
        scanf("%s", &list[i].name);



        printf("\n");

    }

    printf("---------------");

    int j=0;

        for(j;j<n;j++)
    {

        printf("Info about student: %d \n", j+1);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Index: %d \n",list[j].index);
        printf("Name: %s \n" ,list[j].name);

        printf("\n");

    }





    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: For a start, `#include <iostream>` is C++, not C.  You probably need `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Should you be using dynamic memory, like `malloc` or `realloc`?

Comment: You had typedef `students` defined.  Declare `students list[n]` instead of `struct _students list[n];`

Comment: Please clarify what `delete` means? The code already allocated an array of n.  So there is no way to delete any memory.  If you want to make value empty, that is different story.  If you want to add/delete memory, need to use malloc()/free().   You can also use calloc() ore realloc().  Please clarify.

Comment: I just need to delete the last student's info completely out of the list (delete memory), I probably need to make a function that uses malloc or free but I'm not good at that and pointers so I need help, please.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a comment, but i get a message that i need 50 reputation to make a comment.

printf is part of stdio.h so if you use it, you need to include it.

iostream  is not a C library as stated in the comments.

When i ran your code quickly, i got this error.

```
test.c:39:15: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%s", &list[i].name);
```

You have to remember that an array is treated like a pointer. so when you s[],  you do not need the & in front of s in scanf. s is treaded as a pointer to the first element of the array.

```
scanf("%s", list[i].name);
```

Once i removed the & and removed iostream and added stdio.h your code compiled.